# Python 3.5.2: socket.timeout exception causes typeerror

Tags: python-3.x, exception, typeerror

I'm a bit of a Python newbie and this is my first post to stackoverflow so please bear with me. :)
Before posting i have searched google and stackoverflow but cant seem to find anything similar to my issue.

I have a script that polls a website and retrieves the content.
It works fine for hours however if it encounters a socket timeout the script throws a typeerror even though I have an exception for it.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but cant put my finger on it.

Code:

```
timingout = 10

def get_url(url):
  try:
    sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timingout)
    orig_html = sock.read()
    html = orig_html.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore").encode('cp1252', errors='ignore')  
    sock.close()     
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Kill program if Control-C is pressed
        sys.exit(0)
  except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("***Error= Page ", e.reason)
    return
  except timingout:
    print("socket timed out - URL: %s", url)
  else:
    # See if site is Down or errors eg: 404
    if html == None:
        print ("page contains no content!?!")
        return ''
    # See if site is complaining
    elif html == site_overload:
        if _verbose:
            print('ERROR: Too many requests - SLEEPING 600 secs')
        time.sleep(600)
        return ''
    # If not, we are good
    elif html:
        return html
```

error:

```
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
**socket.timeout: timed out**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 140, in main
    http_text = get_text(site_id)
  File "test.py", line 110, in get_text
    return get_url(url)
  File "test.py", line 59, in get_url
    except timingout:
**TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed**
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions & help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by trying to use `timingout` to catch an exception. `timingout` is an integer object whereas the `except` statement only accepts objects inherited from the `BaseException` class.

Remove that `except` because it doesn't do anything. Also consider revising your `try` statement to only include a single operation. It will make troubleshooting easier and prevent you from having to break up your `try` statements later on when a bug occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. i see what ive done now. I will also look to follow your advice about breaking up the try statements. Im very new at this so really appreciate the guidance :)